# Difference between Lighthouse numbers and observed performance

Tags: mobile, lighthouse

I have spent literally weeks chasing the perfect desktop and mobile scores from Google Search Console. My website is new, so there is not enough data, and I'm forced to use Lighthouse.

At 1AM today my score was 97 desktop, 80 mobile. At 2PM today, with no changes, it dropped to 80/32.

I am also being informed that there is a FOIT due to improper loading of code.

I have run these tests dozens of times over the past few weeks, making minor changes and then looking at their impact. I am chasing smoke.

Just before I wrote this note my son and I decided to test real-world timing for the first time. I have a desktop pc, Windows 10, all properly updated. i-5 processor about 3 years old, 12 gb RAM, with a 300 MB/s cable modem connection on ethernet (wired).

Lighthouse speed: Time to Interactive: 1.8s The website loaded so fast it was not measurable with a digital stopwatch,at well under 1 second. Next, we tried mobile connections over home wifi (Netgear Nighthawk AC 1900). First with a Samsung S8 cellphone accessing the website via my Google Ads website link.

Time from pressing the website button to complete load: 1.8 seconds, +/- .2 seconds. Next, my son's iPhone8 plus. Time to complete load: 1.6 seconds, +/- .2 seconds. Lighthouse result: "Time to Interactive"**8.4s**.

The results were close on the desktop, but off by about 400% on the mobile connections. I am a retired doctor with no IT training, but I know where to find the information I need and apply it. I just spent the last 2 weeks chasing numbers that have little relationship to real-world experience; an enormous waste of time.

I suggest that if there is not enough real-life data to assess "time to interactive", that you might be better served not using a service that attempts to mimic real-world experience with such poor correlation. I just wasted a lot of time chasing numbers that tend to arbitrarily change and have no relationship to observable and measurable performance, and I am sure I'm not the only one.

In addition, there was zero observable FOIT on any device, so if it does exist, it is too fast for the human eye to observe, and as such is irrelevant. Knowing this, what is the purpose of the Lighthouse test, why do its numerical scores change so dramatically during the course of a day, and how do the numerical results of such a test improve real-world experience?

Comment: firstly I would rewrite your question to be less of a "rant" and just stick to the factual points, otherwise it might get closed. Secondly you are completely misunderstanding how the mobile part works. The mobile simulates a mid-level phone (slower CPU) and a 4G connection, which introduces latency and slower download / upload. You both have powerful phones compared to most so wouldn't experience lag due to heavy JavaScript loads. Fluctuations in score can be down to load order, poor hosting etc. As you tested at night and day and score was better at night it would point to poor hosting.

Comment: A FOIT is down to how you apply fonts, you need to looking into "font swapping" and "inlining critical CSS" as two things that can solve this. "Time to interactive" is not the same as when you see the page appear. It is when the CPU goes quiet, yet again on a slower device this can be critical as lots of JavaScript can make a page feel "laggy" and ruin the experience. The final thing to consider is the "score" is less important than the information it provides, follow any parts under "opportunities" first and fix them, they WILL impact performance, "diagnostics" is for debugging issues.

Comment: I have marked your question for closing as it does not follow community guidelines but I hope the above information is useful to you. If you edit your question I will remove my vote and will happily help you. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try and only ask one specific question at a time as a general rule on Stack Overflow as otherwise it is hard to get all the points across. I did a very quick tidy up of your question as the wall of text was impossible to read, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: You may want to read the [introduction to Page Speed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/about#lab) and follow a few links (particularly [Core Web Vitals](https://web.dev/vitals/)) to further understand what the tool does, what tests it runs and why it is important. Also [this page explains network throttling](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/docs/throttling.md) that is used in Page Speed Insights.